# How much load database takes when I SELECT ... IN `big_array`?

Tags: sql, select

Let's say, I have accumulated some array of id's (for example `[1, 2, 3, ..., 1000]`). Is wise to SELECT such big array from database. It's not big deal to take array of 10-20 things out of DB, but what if it were 1000-10000?

**EDIT**
Somehow it seems, that `SELECT ... IN (SELECT ....id FROM ... BETWEEN 0 AND 100)` is much slower(about 1200 ms !!!), than just form an `array` and `SELECT ... IN [array]`

Comment: For example time of execution. Will it be too big?

Comment: Time of execution of _what_?

Comment: Of `SELECT ... FROM ... IN [...] ` query

Comment: Then in which DBMS? With which table structure? Is `id` primary key or what? If yes, then 10k readings of PK is _nothing_

Comment: It's most possible, that it will be MySQL. And yes, id is primary key in table. But what if not?

Comment: If it's not - then at best case, it will be just indexed - then 10k reading is ok (but depends of how often that query will be done), or non-indexed - then 10k full-scans will be painful.

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you need to select many (1000+) records based on an array of ID's, a better approach than using the IN-operator, is to load your array of ID's into a temporary table, and then perform a join:

So instead of this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Id IN (...)
```

Do this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempIDs ( Id AS INT );
-- Bulk load the #TempIDs table with the ID's (DON'T issue one INSERT statement per ID!)
SELECT * FROM MyTable INNER JOIN #TempIDs ON MyTable.Id = #TempIDs.Id
```

Note the comment. For best performance, you need a mechanism for bulk loading the temporary table with ID's - this depends on your RDBMS and your application.

Comment: Agree, when you perform IN operation it's just ORing each single value.

Comment: And what if IN [...] were not an array exactly, but subquery?

Comment: Then it's even easier, because in that case you don't need to bulk load anything. Just inner join with your subquery instead.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot. I'll try to figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

### Pressure on parser and optimizer

A query of the kind

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE x.a IN (1,2,3,...,1000)
```

will (at least in Oracle) be transformed to

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE x.a=1 OR x.a=2 OR x.a=3 OR ... OR x.a=1000
```

You will get a very big parser tree and (at least in Oracle) you will hit the limit of the parser tree with more than 1000 values. So you put pressure on the parser and the optimizer and this will cost you some performance. Additionally the database will not be able to use some optimizations.

But there is another problem:

### Fixed number of bind variables

Because your query is transformed into an equivalent query using `OR` expressions, you cannot use bind variables for the IN clause (`SELECT * FROM x WHERE x.a IN (:values)` will *not* work). You can only use bind variables for each value in the IN clause. So when you alter the number of values, you get a structural different query. This puts pressure on the query cache and (at least in Oracle) on the cursor cache.

## Solutions

### Solution: Use ranges

If you can describe your query without numbering each value, it will usually become much faster. E.g. instead of `WHERE a.x in (1,...,1000)` write `WHERE a.x>=1 AND a.x <=1000`.

### Solution: Use a temporary table

This solution is already described in the answer from Dan: Pump your values in an (indexed!) temporary table and use either a nested query (`WHERE a.x IN (SELECT temp.x FROM temp`) or joins (`FROM a JOIN temp USING (x)`, or  `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM temp WHERE temp.x=a.x)`).

**Style guide:** My rule of thumb is to use a nested query when you expected few results in the temp table (mot much more than 1000) and joins when you expect many results (much more than 1000). With modern optimizers there should be no difference, but I think about it a s a hint to the human reader of the query, what the expected amount of values is. I use semi joins (`WHERE EXISTS`) when I don't care about the values in the temporary table in the further query. Again this is more for the human reader than for the SQL optimizer.

### Solution: Use your database's native collection type

When you database has a native collection type, you can also use this in your query (e.g. `TYPE nested_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20)


This will make your code non portable (usually not a big problem, because people switch their database engine very rarely in an established project).
This might make your code hard to read (at least for developers to being that experienced with your brand of SQL database).


An example for Oracle:

DECLARE
  TYPE ILIST IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
  temp ILIST := ILIST();
  result VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  temp.extend(3);
  temp(1) := 1;
  temp(2) := 2;
  temp(3) := 3;

  SELECT a.y INTO result
  FROM a WHERE a.x IN (select * from TABLE(temp));
END;
/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ranges are not possible, because values are not constant. And solution with collections is still too complicated for newbie like me :) So I'll try to join tables.